# How to add a touch event to a draw Obejct Cocos2 JS HTML5

Tags: events, listener, cocos2d-js

Hello I drew a triangle and now I am wondering how I can add a listener to it.

```
var dn = new cc.DrawNode();
this.addChild(dn);
var w=200;
var h=500;
var star = [
    cc.p(w,h), cc.p(w, h-200), cc.p(w*2, h-100 )
];
dn.drawPoly(star, cc.color(255,255,255,128), 1, cc.color(255,255,255,128) );
```

I tried it with this, but this doesnt work.

```
cc.eventManager.addListener({
    event: cc.EventListener.MOUSE,
    onMouseMove: function(event){
        var str = "MousePosition X: " + event.getLocationX() + "  Y:" + event.getLocationY();
        // do something...
    },
    onMouseUp: function(event){
        var str = "Mouse Up detected, Key: " + event.getButton();
        // do something...
    },
    onMouseDown: function(event){
        var str = "Mouse Down detected, Key: " + event.getButton();
        // do something...
    },
    onMouseScroll: function(event){
        var str = "Mouse Scroll detected, X: " + event.getLocationX() + "  Y:" + event.getLocationY();
        // do something...
    }
},dn);
```

It just dispaches when I click and not only when I click on the triangle.

Answer (score 0):

use cc.EventListener.TOUCH_ONE_BY_ONE instead

and callbacks are onTouchBegan(), onTouchEnded(), onTouchCancelled(), onTouchMoved()

Answer (score 0):

That's how all events work actually.

You need to add, in each of your event functions, a check to see whether the touched coordinates are within the object, like so:

```
onTouchesEnded: function (touches, event) {
    var touch = touches[0];

    if(cc.rectContainsPoint(event.getCurrentTarget().getBoundingBox(), touch.getLocation())){
      console.log("event within object!");
    }
}
```